# appengine api methods return model collection

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, android-gradle-plugin

I have successfully created an appengine project in android studio and am trying to use it within an Android client. I am getting errors when i call a `List<Student>` api method from my backend saying i should be returning a model collection. Here is my code to show examples of what i am talking about:

```
StudentEndpoint service = AppConstants.getApiHandle();
            stud = service.getStudents().execute(); //this is the error
            list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            _list = stud.getItems();
            for (Student student : _list) {
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("email", student.getEmail());
                hm.put("school", student.getSchool());
                list.add(hm);
            }

            String from[] = {"email", "school"};
            int to[] = {R.id.email, R.id.school};
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.listlay, from, to);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

stud is declared as a `List<Student>`

here is the api method for getAllStudents():

```
@ApiMethod(name="getStudents")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return ofy().load().type(Student.class).list();
    }
```

The error is saying: required java.util.List found appbackend_path....StudentCollection

appbackend_path is just referring to the package name for my backend api. So my question really is why is this returning a StudentCollection instead of a List?

I have tried to make the 'stud' variable a StudentCollection and it gets rid of the compilation errors and builds the application onto my phone but when i try and populate the listview i get this exception:

```
07-28 21:21:43.566  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-28 21:21:43.566  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-28 21:21:43.566  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:29)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:245)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:189)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:369)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.nicky.communitybeta.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:50)           //same line as error i am referring to above
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
07-28 21:21:43.567  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
07-28 21:21:43.568  31789-31789/com.nicky.communitybeta W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if you need to see any more files or gradle setup. The api works when i use the localhost/_ah/api/explorer build, I can add students list them etc. and everything shows up as expected.

EDIT:
After much more reading and testing different things out i have got it working and figured out why I was getting errors and in the case anyone else has the same errors this is my fix:

I should not have been using `List<Student>` for the api method in my backend, and instead be using a CollectionResponse as i have here:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "getAllStudents")
    public CollectionResponse<Student> getAllStudents() {

        List<Student> stud = ofy().load().type(Student.class).list();
        return CollectionResponse.<Student>builder().setItems(stud).build();
    }
```

and then in the client code i was receiving the first error because i need to set the call to `service.getAllStudents().execute()` as a CollectionResponseStudent like so:

```
StudentEndpoint service = AppConstants.getApiHandle();
            CollectionResponseStudent stud = service.getAllStudents().execute();
```

and after figuring that out i needed to wrap it all in an AsyncTask. Too much network traffic on the main thread was causing that exception as shown above. It is now creating and consuming appengine data in an android client.

Comment: It is actually a bug that List<Student> doesn't work. It should automatically wrap into a CollectionResponse-like schema. If you wouldn't mind file a bug, that would be great: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry Just be sure to add a Component-Endpoints tag.

Answer (score 1):

The **App Engine** auto generated `ObjectCollection` class returned by the API method has a method called `getItems()`
which will return a `List<yourObject>` (in your case `List<Student>`),
Just add `.getItems()` after `.execute()` and you should get your result.